# Copying Hyper V files from one NVME drive to another

Tags: file-transfer, hyper-v

I'm trying to copy all my Hyper V machines from one (smaller) NVME drive to another (larger) so I can have more disk space.

I have shut down all hyper v instances and switched off the service.

I have used robocopy and windows copy paste but I keep getting problems with some files, mostly the vhdx files:

Error 0x800070079: The semaphore timeout period has expired.

Here is the error message in it's entirety:

[image]

Anyone know how to get round this?

Comment: How is the second NVME drive connected, an m.2 on the motherboard or via usb? That error usually means the copy was interrupted at some lower level that windows can't really see. It can be driver issues (especially with usb/storage controller/motherboard drivers), faulty connection (try unplug/replug), issues with the harddrive itself being faulty, or sometimes antivirus interference. Since it happens on larger copies, try and check whether it's overheating

Comment: @Vidar - What happens when you create a clone of the virtual HDD?

Comment: I have one on the motherboard and another on a USB 3 external dock.

Comment: @Vidar then yeah, definitely try updating your USB drivers, and see if the dock has any drivers for it specifically. Seems like that's the most common situation other people see this error in as well. It shouldn't have anything to do with HyperV at least

Comment: I did have similar errors when trying to copy from one drive to a network drive - or to another internal (slow) hard drive. So I'm not so sure its driver issues really.